# SQL to get data current_Datetime Minus 5 years?

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the data for the patients who did not come to the hospital in from current date minus 5 years? Can someone please tell me where am I making mistake?

```
Select Patient_Name, Record_Id, Address
from PatientDate
where last_VisitDate = DATEDIFF(years, GETDATE(), -5)
```

Comment: What's the error or result that you get?

Comment: In standard SQL: `current_timestamp - interval '5' year`

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Do you mean exactly 5 years ago to the date or do you mean 5 years ago *or* later. There is a difference. 5 years exactly would basically only yield a result on the 5 year anniversary date of the last visit. 5 years and older is any patient who's last visit was 5 years ago *or* later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are usinq SQL Server.

You would need

```
where last_VisitDate <= DATEADD(year,-5, GETDATE())
```

`DATEDIFF` returns an `int` and expects as inputs a datepart, a startdate and an enddate. It is used to return the difference between two dates. You should pay attention when using DATEDIFF because of how datepart bounderies are interpreted. You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: That will never yield result... unless you happen to run it at exactly the right *time* (hint).

Comment: good catch. i was just focusing on the improper use of the function